# how get only specific fields from elsticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

i have elasticsearch indice i have  filed name "titile":Rolex i want to write DSL to save
ratemax,ratemin fields as variable

can this be done here is my sample json

```
 "vente": [
      "62402c696a271a7d0ceeef2f"
    ],
    "status": [
      0
    ]
  },
  "ignored_field_values": {
    "description.keyword": [
      "ROLEX  \nPRINCE BRANCARD \"EATON QUARTER CENTURY CLUB\"  \nVERS 1930  \nMontre bracelet en or jaune 14K sur cuir.   \nBOITIER : rectangulaire curvex cintré en or jaune 14K (belle oxydation de l'or). Fond gravé d'une dédicace: \"Presented to Fred Peartree to mark a quarter century of continuous service with the T. Eaton, 1916-1941.\"   \nCADRAN : duodial, argenté deux tons, personnalisé Eaton, inscrit \"1/4 Century Club\" à la place des index. Aiguilles en acier bleui.  \nMOUVEMENT: mécanique, certifié chronometre, Ultra-Prima.   \nBRACELET : cuir avec boucle ardillon en or Rolex.  \nBoîtier et mouvement signés Rolex.  \nNumérotée 53207.  \nDIM. 42 x 24 mm.  \n \nCette montre fait partie d'une série personnalisée par un industriel canadien nommé Eaton. Cet entrepreneur avait l'habitude d'en faire cadeau à ses employés pour les remercier de leur fidélité.  \nA 14K gold manual winding wristwatch by Rolex from the 30's."
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain in details?

Comment: Hi amit , i have 2 indices  let say  lot1 ,lot2   lot 1 has the  product name and Lot2 has store name where the product is available  the common filed between two indices is vente so  in the lot1 i have the brand name (rolex) which i can search , but i nee to read the value of vente filed (62402c696a271a7d0ceeef2f) and then use that  query string in Lot2 wich has the storename